# How to copy a file from the terminal, then paste it on the browser?

Tags: command-line, files, gnome-terminal, filemanager, clipboard

I'm using Ranger as my file manager but every time I want to send something like an image (by copy pasting) I need to open the GUI file manager, copy the file, and paste it on the browser.

How to achieve this with any type of binary file on the terminal? (Image, pdf, etc)

Comment: How exactly are you sending the file via browser? By uploading it through some web form? In that case the form should have a "Browse" button (or similar, may be called "Add file", "Select file" etc.) which allows you to just open the regular file selection dialog. You can either select the file by clicking on it or paste the full path to the file (which you may copy from terminal) into the dialog.

Comment: @raj For example, if you paste an image from your clipboard to WhatsApp Web, it automatically uploads.

Comment: You are mixing different layers. It's one thing to cut and paste **data** over clipboard from one app to another (in terminal, you could cut and paste only text this way, as terminal is a text mode app), and it's a completely another thing to upload a **file** from the disk in your computer to some web app via upload form. The feature you write about (pasting image from clipboard to a web app) is a specific feature of the app in question, and you can't think of it as some general capability that is available anywhere.

Comment: And if you are asking for a way to display eg. image file, pdf file etc. so that you can copy it to clipboard, in a terminal, without opening a GUI file manager, then use the command `xdg-open <path to file>`. It will open the file in it's assigned application, ie. images in image viewer, pdf files in PDF viewer etc.

Comment: It's pretty sad that it can't be done, but I will try that command that you suggest. Otherwise, I will keep copying using the GUI.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it can be done with that command. I'm just not sure if I understood you correctly, because your question is not very clear.

Comment: But why not just upload the file directly instead of playing with cut and paste? If the application accepts pasted image, it will surely accept a direct file upload.

Comment: I was wondering if it could be done on the terminal, instead of using drag-and-drop or copying the file with Nautilus or any other file manager.

Comment: But the problem is, you don't specify clearly **what exactly** it is that you want done on the terminal. There are several possibilities: if you want to upload the file, you can do it using the file picker. If you want to cut and paste the contents, you can `xdg-open` the file in the terminal and then cut and paste. What **exactly and precisely** do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

In ranger on your desired file press <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. The full path of the file would be copied into your clipboard.

Then paste it anywhere you want in your browser like an upload field.

---

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> in ranger is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>   of GUI File Managers.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I don't know if it helps, but the command is `echo -n %d/%f` and then it's piped to `xsel` two times

Comment: I can't achieve what you explained in the comment section (About WhatsApp web). If you could clearify what you exactly want using we might be able to help you. otherwise my answer is demonstrating the exact alternative of a copy-paste action in Ranger file manager. And you end-up with the file path in your clipboard.

Comment: Don't worry. The thing I wanted to do can't be done, but it's okay, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the OP's quesstion correctly, this can be achieved by using `xclip`.

Example use:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png /tmp/example.png
```

You would have to adapt this example to include it in a ranger map or script, particularly if you want to automate the recognition of various mime types.

A command that may help do this is `file -b --mime-type example-file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command in ranger:

```
:shell echo -n file://%d/%f | xclip -selection c -t text/uri-list
```

Explanation:

As @asoundmove pointed out, the MIME type of the file you want to copy matters. You can display the MIME type targets of the clipboard with `xclip`. E.g. when I copy an image with `gthumb`, I get the following:

```
 xclip -selection c -o -t TARGETS
TIMESTAMP
TARGETS
MULTIPLE
x-special/gnome-copied-files
text/uri-list
UTF8_STRING
COMPOUND_TEXT
TEXT
STRING
text/plain;charset=utf-8
text/plain
```

To print the contents of the clipboard for a specific target MIME type, do the following:

```
$ xclip -selection c -o -t text/uri-list
file:///home/username/image.jpg
```

or

```
$ xclip -selection c -o -t x-special/gnome-copied-files
copy
file:///home/username/image.jpg
```

To copy an uri to the clipboard so that it can be interpreted by your GUI application (e.g. a file browser), you need to know in which format that application expects the data to be in. Often, text/uri-list works. You can achieve what you want as follows:

```
echo -n file:///home/username/image.jpg | xclip -selection c -t text/uri-list
```